# Pythonic way to extract elements from heapq

Tags: python, python-2.7, priority-queue

I am using a **priority queue** (`heapq`) with `datetime.datetime` as priority.

What is the most pythonic way to extract a subset of element from this list if I have the startTime and endTime to search for.
(I can not alter the original list, so I must create a new list and return, or return an iterator)

Below is an example of what I have:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> timeLine = []
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> heapq.heappush(timeLine, (datetime.now(),'A'))
>>> heapq.heappush(timeLine, (datetime.now(),'B'))
>>> heapq.heappush(timeLine, (datetime.now(),'C'))
>>> timeLine
[(datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 8, 15, 25, 14, 720000), 'A'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 8, 15, 25, 30, 575000), 'B'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 8, 15, 25, 36, 959000), 'C')]
```

The real application-list is huge.

Comment: Heaps aren't the best choice here. They are good if you want to extract min/max, not for finding generic elements. Probably the simplest thing to do is sort the list and use binary search on the result.

Comment: Well, actually it should be faster to simply scan the whole array and filter out the datetimes outside the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heaps are not the ideal structure to perform this operation; if you stick to `heapq`'s public API, the heap will be altered and made useless for further operations. @Anonymous' solution may work, but (IMHO) relies too much on implementation details. While these are publicly documented, I'm not sure if you should really be using them.

Simply sorting the list and doing two binary searches is an easy way to do what you want:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

def find_range(timeline, start, end):
    l = bisect_left(timeline, start)
    r = bisect_right(timeline, end)
    for i in xrange(l, r):
        yield timeline[i]
```

The only trouble with this approach is that sorting takes O(*n* lg *n*) time in the worst case, but then so does your way of constructing the heap (`heapq.heapify` would take linear time).

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply, but what do you mean with heapq.heapify, how would that help (the searching)?

Comment: @theAlse It builds heaps faster than `heappush` in a loop, if you have all the elements up front.

Comment: I get the following error testing the code above:
l = bisect_left(timeline, startTime)
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple

Comment: @theAlse: try searching for `(startTime, '')` and `(endTime, '')` instead. That should work if your endtime is exclusive, I think.

Comment: still no go. says that the argument should be integer

Comment: @theAlse: I'm sorry, but I can't debug your application from here. If `bisect` doesn't work at all, you might try the `blist` package from http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/, that supports (very large) sorted key-value stores.

Answer (score 0):

Every node in a heap is larger than all its children. Also, if the node is at index i, its immediate children are at indices 2 * i + 1 and 2 * i + 2.

Viewing the heap as a binary tree, you can recurse down the heap, stopping if an entry is bigger than the maxkey you've got (since all its children will be larger), and outputting the node if its key is between minkey and maxkey.

Putting this together gives this:

```
def extract_range(h, i, minkey, maxkey):
    if i >= len(h) or h[i][0] >= maxkey:
        return
    if h[i][0] >= minkey:
        yield h[i]
    for k in 1, 2:
        for r in extract_range(h, 2 * i + k, minkey, maxkey):
            yield r
```